# Receive IDE events in Visual Studio extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, plugins

I've never wrote any extension for Visual Studio but I want to write one that is helpful to me. So I have a question about way how to implement it. Basically, I want to write code which will receive different IDE events, like:

- build/clean completed
- Tests run completed
- etc

I wasn't able to find that information. Can someone suggest at least direction where to dig?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the [DTE2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.dte2.aspx) object:

   DTE2 dte = (DTE2)GetService(typeof(DTE));
2. Get the [Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.events.aspx) object from the dte.Events property.
3. Subscribe to events.